# Reuse Bazel build cache in multi repo setup

Tags: bazel

I have a huge project in a multi repo setup with one `WORKSPACE` file in the root directory and a `WORKSPACE` file in each of the underlying repos:

```
myproject/
   BUILD
   WORKSPACE
   repo-a/
      WORKSPACE
   repo-b/
      WORKSPACE
   repo-c/
      WORKSPACE
```

where the `BUILD` file of the project root merely refers to underlying build targets:

```
alias(
   name = "main",
   actual = "@repo-a//foo/bar:hello"
)
```

I can build either the entire project by starting the build in the root directory:

```
myproject $ bazel build main
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target @repo-a//foo/bar:hello up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/external/repo-a/foo/bar/hello
```

or build a specific module/leaf of the project by starting the build in a specific sub-repo:

```
myproject $ cd repo-a
myproject/repo-a $ bazel build //...
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //foo/bar:hello up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo/bar/hello
```

Unfortunately, Bazel sees this as two different builds and is not re-using the cached results of the other build. Probably because the path to the target is different `@repo-a//foo/bar:hello` versus `//foo/bar:hello`

Can I hint Bazel to cache differently (e.g. by prefixing the `@repo-a` module name in the leaf build)?

Answer (score 0):

In the general sense of the term "caching" meaning re-using pre-computed data, Bazel implements different levels of caching:

- The bazel server (a daemon process) keeps an in-memory copy of the build graph, and remembers which actions (command-line args) need to be re-computed/re-executed based on changed files
- Once an action is computed (what command-line to run, and what input files to use) bazel can consult a remote cache to see if this command has already been executed, and fetch the resulting outputs if so

A bazel server is started for each working directory, so once you `cd` into one of your children bazel workspaces, a second bazel server is started, and it must re-parse the BUILD files in that workspace, and maintain its own copy of the build graph in-memory. AFAIK, there is no way to deduplicate this.

However, you can configure bazel to deduplicate executed commands with a "remote" cache. This means that regardless of workspace, if a build step shares the same command with the same input file contents and same arguments with a previously-executed build step, bazel will not have to re-run that command. Since the bulk of build time are these commands, this would speed things up greatly.

The easiest way to configure a remote cache is to point the `--disk_cache` flag at a directory for invocations in every workspace (using the same directory for each). However, this flag has some caveats:

- It does not enforce an upper bound on storage used, so one needs to delete data from it manually periodically
- Interactions with other remote caching flags may produce surprising behavior (depending on which version of bazel one is using)

Another approach is to set up a bazel cache instance on the same machine, and configure bazel in each workspace to use the machine's cache via an HTTP/gRPC IP:port or UNIX socket. More info on this and the `--disk_cache` flag can be found in the [bazel docs](https://bazel.build/remote/caching)